# Avoid "." and ".." directories in FTP

Tags: java

When I retrieve FTP files using Apache commons API, I am getting "." and ".." directories in all directories including sub-directories.  How can I avoid those two directories? Can anybody suggest me?

my code is:

```
client.changeWorkingDirectory("/");
String[] names = client.listNames();
for (String name : names) {
System.out.println("File Name = " + name);
}
FTPFile[] ftpFiles = client.listFiles(); // Want to eliminate "." and ".." files 

output: 
File Name = .
File Name = ..
File Name = .ftpquota
File Name = file1
File Name = file2
```

Comment: Just remove them from the array afterwards? They're part of the standard result from a `LIST` command.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to filter them out (they represent the *current* and *parent* directory, respectively and FTP will automatically report these to you).

Perhaps use the Apache Commons Collections [filter](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) mechanism ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FTPFileFilter`](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFileFilter.html) and the api 
 `listFiles(String pathname, FTPFileFilter filter)` 
In your `FTPFileFilter` class check if `FTPFile.isDirectory()` and check the name.